# how to limit keys in TypeScript Object?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

i am trying to get the typing correct for this example:

```
type ElementTypes = "trees" | "parcels"


export const config: {
  [nationState in NationStateType]: Record<ElementTypes, WFSConfigurations[]>
} = {
  city: { // city is a key in NationStateType
    trees: [
      // WFSCOnfigurations...
    ],
  },
}
```

right now TS forces me to have all keys from ElementTypes (trees & parcels) in `city`
so instead i want it to be ok to only use one key from ElementTypes. How would i do that?

Comment: `Partial<Record<...>>`?

Comment: sorry... you are totally right :/ should have found it on my own. Thanks tho ;)